# How should I connect the windings of this induction motor to make it work?

Tags: connector, wiring, induction-motor

I took this motor from an old washing machine and I'd like to make it work.

[image]
[image]

The motor has the following specifications:

- Input voltage: 220 V 50 Hz
- Number of poles: 2/12
- RPM: 420/2820
- Rated power: 0.12/0.08 HP
- Capacitor needed: 14 uF / 450 V

I tried to draw a schematic of the motor by using a multimeter to measure the resistance of the windings (of course the schematic is just for connection purposes and not for modelling since it lacks inductance and slip). However I'm not 100% sure I got it right. The schematic is as below:
[image]
[image]

In the schematic, M8 is the neutral while the phase is marked with L. According to the connection box, it looks like the neutral should be wire M8. In the connection, the capacitor is connected in series with a winding and the motor should work at low speed (12 poles). What I don't understand is that when I measure the resistance across m4 and m5 I get 90 ohm instead of the expected 140 ohm (given by 70 + 70). While for all the other permutations of connection the measurements check out, this is not true for the series of m4 and m5 as you can see from the schematic.

This thing leaves me a bit of doubt on whether I understood or not the internal wiring of the motor. Could you please help me to shed some light on this?

Comment: Hmmm...  I'm guessing from the contact numbers all being Ms that you have some sort of IEC motor.  If you can figure out what type, the contact numbers are probably standard.

Comment: Oh by the way if you still have the washing machine, if you take apart the casing of home appliances you will often find complete repair documents including schematics.  You can use the original schematic to deduce the use of the coils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis certainly makes sense with respect to identifying the common point and the two pairs of windings. The resistance between M4 and M5 is indeed a mystery. I assume that you rechecked your measurements. There is a possibility that there is a short between the M4 and M5 winding at some point. If that is the case, it would likely be a fault rather than a feature of the motor design.

There are a lot of ways that single-phase induction motors are designed, but a 2/12 pole motor would need to have two completely independent sets of windings. Each set of windings would need to have the capacitor in series with one winding. It is possible that one capacitor could be used for that.

As mentioned in a comment, diagrams and other information is often attached to the back or inside the back of the machine. Any additional information that you can find would help. There are diagrams online for various designs of motors and washing machine control schemes. If you decide to apply power, it would be good to have an ammeter connected and know what current to expect. There should be a marking on the machine indicating maximum current.

Comment: Yes, I checked and double checked the measurements. The machine according to the owner could work but it had not been turned on for years. A fault might be the explanation for the M4-5 connection. The machine has more than 10 years, I hope I can find something online. The only data on the motor was the one I reported. A single capacitor was used.

Comment: The single capacitor could be switched from one winding to the other when the speed changes. It is also possible that the high speed is only switched in while it is running at low speed. It might not need the capacitor in that cale.

Answer (score 1):

I saw late the post, but maybe it'll be useful to somebody. Probably the diagram is like that:[image]

Comment: Welcome to electronics SX! This site includes a tool to draw circuit diagramms for your answer - this makes them easier to read, smaller in file size - and also includes them in correct orientation ;)
Would you care to edit your answer with the circuit diagramm tool?